# Get MIN value for each type from an unsorted dataset with multiple types using Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In col A, I have a mix of data that starts with a data type identifier, followed by a value, all semi-colon separated e.g.

```
a_3;b_2;c_4;c_5;b_2;a_1;a_7;b_9
```

In col B, I have just the data type identifiers listed in the following manner:
a;b;c

In col C, I am struggling to write a formula that would return the minimum number value for each of the corresponding data types in col B.

So, as per above, the values are a_3;a_1;a_7, thus the minimum value for 'a' is "1". Likewise minimum for 'b' is "2" and the minimum for 'c' is "4".

The return value to be displayed in Col C would thus be:
1;2;4

I wrote an `ARRAYFORMULA` that creates a 2d array where its first row only contains 'a' values, row two only has 'b' values and row three has 'c' values.
e.g.

```
3 1 7
   2 2 9
      4 5
```

But I have no idea how I can feed each separate row to a `MIN` function (which would itself have to be inside some kind of array formula that would iterate over the above array one row at a time).

Maybe this is a flawed approach and I need to think about the solution differently.

to summarize:

```
Col A                                Col B      Col C
a_3;b_2;c_4;c_5;b_2;a_1;a_7;b_9      a;b;c      1;2;4
```

I need the formula to produce the result in Col C.

Here is the example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k1K7_msW8Jd_9-18zKdgdFKsSSYrRLtYjTLolQsAVjQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",1,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2,";")),
 SORTN({REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,";")),"[A-Za-z]+"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,";")),"\d+")},COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,";")))),2,0),)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I am starting to read the links you left in the example sheet. For right now, if I change my type identifiers to the following "01_0" or "01_1" or "06_0" etc followed by ">" character followed by my number values (which I'd like to format as "000"), I see that [A-Za-z]+ no longer works, because clearly that only covers "letters". Is there an easy change to this [ ] bracketed stuff to allow to split but using the number/underscore combination? (mind you, I try to make sure my data type identifiers are always the same width, if that helps).

Comment: `=ArrayFormula({REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(F34,";")),"\d+_\d+"),
  SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(F34,";")),">\d+"),">","")})`

Comment: I am in trouble. Turns out your code doesn't quite work. I tried to change the thing in the example sheet from this a_2;a_3;b_5;a_5;b_7 to this a_2;a_3;b_5;a_5;b_1. I was expecting the min value for "b" to change from 5 to 1, but it didn't.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(";",1,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B3,";")),
 SORTN({REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A3,";")),"[A-Za-z]+"),
  REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A3,";")),"\d+")},COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A3,";")))),2,0),)))`

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thanks.